# How do you save a Byte array in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, arrays

How do you save a byte array into a cell in SQL using only SQL or SQL Server Management Studio?

I converted an image into a byte array, and now I have a 1,000+ line byte array that I want saved in a (`varbinary(max)`)cell in SQL.

Trying to execute a simple update command fails:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [Image] = 'lengthy string
with over
1000 hard returned lines'
WHERE [ItemKey] = 1
```

But this only gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Removing the WHERE clause (which makes no sense because I need to specify what row of data I'm trying to save this to) manages to get the error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I'm clearly doing something wrong and I'm not sure what. I've looked around and everybody seems to be doing this in the C# code which would be fine if I needed to do this more frequently but I'm just trying to put this data in a single cell one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that inserts, updates, and selects the data back:

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE
(
  [Cell] INT,
  [Image] VARBINARY(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @TableName VALUES (1, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'Test'))

UPDATE @TableName
SET [Image] = (CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'lengthy string
with over
1000 hard returned lines'))
WHERE [Cell] = 1

SELECT [Image] FROM @TableName

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [Image]) FROM @TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63743/converting-a-varchar-to-varbinary

Something like this is what you need to wrap around your data

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(25), '0x9473FBCCBC01AF', 1);
```