# C# SQL to get a picture from the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void LoginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var loguser = AutorizeLoginBox.Text;
    var passuser = AutorizePasswordBox.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    string querystring = $"select ID, USERLOGIN, USERPASSWORD, USERAVATAR from USERTESTDB where USERLOGIN='{loguser}' and USERPASSWORD='{passuser}'";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, sqldb.getConnection());

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(table);

    if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        byte[] arr;
        Image imgcur;
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertFromString(table.Rows[0].ToString(), );
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr);
        Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
        Program.programpg.avatarbox.Image = i;
    }
}
```

How to upload the image assigned to this user in the database after login. //symbolforfixdetails//symbolforfixdetails//symbolforfixdetails//symbolforfixdetails

This is how the database looks like:

[image]

Error is on this line:

```
arr = (byte[])converter.ConvertFromString(table.Rows[0].ToString() );
```

Error:

> System.NotSupportedException: "ImageConverter cannot convert from System.String."

Comment: Via another instance of SqlCommand, using the same connection, you can execute an UPDATE or INSERT statement as shown in this post:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382870/how-do-you-save-a-byte-array-in-sql.

Comment: I need to upload a picture from the database to picturebox

Comment: Where exact is the problem ? Does the memorystream not gets populated ? Or does the Image not gets loaded ? Or something else ?

Comment: I don't understand how to pull an image from the database and upload it to picturebox @GuidoG

Comment: You need to post the code that stores the images. Or, specify whether the `USERAVATAR` Column is `VARBINARY(MAX)`, a string storing a base64 encoded array or, e.g., the path/name of a file on disk.

Comment: Have you debugged the code you have ? Can you tell where it goes wrong ? And how are the images stored in your database ? As a path or as a binary ?

Comment: add new information

Comment: You shouldn't be using `IMAGE`, it should be replaced with `VARBINARY(MAX)`. It's a byte array anyway, so you have `var image = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(table.Rows[0]["USERAVATAR"]);` -- Assuming the Image was stored correctly and it's not DBNull.

Comment: The `image` datatype is deprecated, you should not use it, use varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612039/why-is-my-image-from-database-not-displaying-properly-in-my-picturebox/66616751#66616751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to set the `PictureBox.Image` from image stored in SQL Server. The code is tested and works as intended.

Part 1: retrieve image from database and set it to `PictureBox.Image`:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
byte[] arr=null;

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
   cn.Open();
   using (SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 1 USERAVATAR from USERTESTDB", cn))  // Replace SQL query with yours
      {
         ad.Fill(table);
      }
 }

 arr = (byte[])table.Rows[0][0];

 // Replace it with [0][3] according to your posted query
 System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = null;
 ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
 System.Drawing.Image img = 
 (System.Drawing.Image)converter.ConvertFrom(arr);
 bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)img;
 pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Part 2: store image in database:

```
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
byte[] img = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("insert into USERTESTDB Values (@img)",cn))
        {
            cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
  }
```

You didn't asked about Part2, but I included it to ensure that the image is stored correctly (as binary data) in the database.

You have two problems with your line of code

```
arr = byte[])converter.ConvertFromString(table.Rows[0].ToString());
```

1. You used `table.Rows[0]` (which returns the entire row) instead of `table.Rows[0][x]` where x = the index of image column.
2. You can't convert `String` to `Image` in this way, check question [3594239](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594239/how-can-i-use-imageformatconverter-convertfromstring-to-convert-a-string-contain) for more details.

Comment: The name "cs" does not exist in the current context. 
```using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs))```

Comment: This is the name of `connection string` I used.

Comment: @xXKoksMenXx, you are using sqldb.getConnection(), so you can replace cs with sqldb.getConnection().ConnectionString

Comment: I made a separate project where I tested your code, everything worked, thank you very much, it remains only to transfer it to my project

Comment: @xXKoksMenXx, Happy for  that :), you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Please Set your Db Column Data type to `Varbinary(Max)` which you store image's bytes.

Then read this binary to a `MemoryStream()` as you did but without convert.

If its a `winforms` project there should be an overload in `PictureBox`'s `DataSource` (or whatever its name. if i don't remember wrong its name is `Image` or `BackgroundImage`) as it accepts directly `byte` array.

If Winforms, Either you can pass as byte array or Convert to an `Image` object and set it to datasource.

But if its a web project, then either you could set it as a `base64 data/png string` or `Image` object.

Hope this helps.